# How to solve Null Pointer Exception while using array?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

Here its showing null pointer exception in the line `arr[i] = "true"`;

```
String[] count = null;
String[] arr = null;
int i = 0;
rs2 = st2.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) as y FROM " + usrtbl + " WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT  user_id FROM " + usrroletbl + ")");
rs2.next();
if (rs2.getInt("y") == 0) {
    arr[i] = "false";
    count = arr;
    i++;
} else {
    arr[i] = "true";
    count = arr;
    i++;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How can you access `arr[0]` ? when you declared `String[] arr=null;`

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `arr` to be `null` *and* you have not allocated it any memory. So of course, accessing `arr[i]` will result in a `NullPointerException`.

You could first run an SQL query to get the number of results and allocate the space, eg.

```
arr = new String[<count>];
```

Or you could use an `ArrayList` to hold the values. This is simpler as it will grow dynamically to hold your data.

As an aside, you should consider converting `arr` (or your `ArrayList`) to hold `boolean`. Then you can use `true` and `false` directly (rather than their string equivalents).

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the `String[] array`

**Approach 1**

```
String[] errorSoon = new String[100]; // <--initialized statement, this is fixed size array, so you need to set the size accordingly, keeping memory usage in mind.
```

**Approach2**

use List

```
List<String> errorSoon  = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Also as mentioned by @dave, if it is really required to have array here, or just a `boolean variable` can work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dave said you have declared both the String arrays as null, so of course you will get NullPointerException. You have to know the size of your resultset first and then declare the array according to the size.

But instead of that I would recommend you to use ArrayList. Its simple and can dynamically add your result. You can do something like this-

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()){
if(// your condition){
   list.add("something");
}
else{
   list.add("something");
}
}
```

So it will keep on adding "something" in the list till the last row is covered.
Then you can easily iterate through the list as per your requirement.
Or you can also convert the ArrayList into an Array using the following command-

```
Object obj[]=list.toArray(); //Note that it will create an Array of Object datatype. You have to typecast it to your required datatype later if you want to print or manipulate the data.
```